# Is it possible to find intersection of circle and triangle?

Tags: analytic-geometry

[image: Example Picture]

Is it possible to find a the exact points a circle will intersect the legs / hypotenuse of a Right 45° triangle?

In the picture above it would be the points that are green which are unknown, but the circle radius and location are known as well as all aspects of the triangle (angles, leg lengths, etc).

Comment: Circle center should be (73,-93) instead of (73,93).

Comment: Did you search for intersection of a line with a circle? You now have three potential lines to check.

Comment: Yep, it should be. I've changed the picture to reflect that.

Comment: (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2678826/find-intersection-of-circle-within-triangle) In the future, please edit your questions instead of asking new questions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find Intersection of Circle within Triangle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2678826/find-intersection-of-circle-within-triangle)

Comment: I did edit it but the edit was rejected. I'm not sure I follow how to make it any clearer or get it unrejected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. The equation of the circle with center $(a,b)$ and radius $r$ is $$(x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2 = r^2$$ while the equation of the horizontal line is $y = -100$. Plugging it in you get $$(x-73)^2 + (-100+93)^2 = r^2$$ and $r$ is fixed, so there will be $2$ solutions which are your points.

For the hypotenuse, it's the equation $x=-y$ you need, and plugging it in you get another quadratic in $x$...

**UPDATE**

With $r=19$ you get $$(x-73)^2 = 19^2 - 7^2 = 312$$ which yields $$x =\ 73 \pm \sqrt{312} \approx 73 \pm 17.66 = \{90.66, 55.34 \}$$

For the second one, with $y=-x$ you get $$(x-73)^2 + (-x + 93)^2 = 19^2$$ you get $$x = 83 \pm \sqrt{\frac{161}{2}} \approx \{74.03, 91.97\}.$$

Comment: The line equations should be $y=100$ and $y=x$. Am I wrong?

Comment: @gimusi fixed. just noitced he inverted the system of coordinates on the picture...

Comment: The inverted was unintentional. I've updated the picture to show the correct coordinates.

Comment: @Robbie updated for new picture and coordinates

Comment: @gimusi That doesn't seem to be showing the correct location of the point. So Mathing it out:
**Step 1:** (x-73)^2 + (49) = 361 
**Step 2:** (x-73)^2 = 312  
**Step 3:** x^2 - 5329 = 312 
**Step 4:** x^2  = 5641
**Step 5:**  x = 75.1

But none of the points there show (75.1,-100)

Comment: @Robbie wrong step 3 see update

Comment: Hmm... Even with the update it doesn't seem to be accurate. 
In the diagram there are no points at {90.66 , 55.34} or {74.03 , 91.97}

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Note that

- circle equation is $(x-73)^2+(y-93)^2=19^2$
- line equations are $y=100$ and $y=x$
- solve the systems of circle with each line to find intersection points

that is

$$\begin{cases}(x-73)^2+(y-93)^2=19^2\\\\y=100 \end{cases}\implies \begin{cases}(x-73)^2+(100-93)^2=19^2\\\\y=100 \end{cases}$$

and

$$\begin{cases}(x-73)^2+(y-93)^2=19^2\\\\y=x \end{cases}\implies \begin{cases}(x-73)^2+(x-93)^2=19^2\\\\y=100 \end{cases}$$

for each system solve the quadratic equation in $x$ and find the intersection points.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach:

Suppose the center of the circle is $I$. Since the coordinates of $I$ is $(73,-93)$, the vertical distance from $I$ to leg $a$ (say $IR$) is: $-93-(-100)=7$.

Suppose two intersection of circle with leg $a$ are $P$ and $Q$, thus $IP=IQ=19$ (since the radius of the circle is $19$). Aware also that it can be proved by geometry of circle that $PR=QR$ and hence, the coordinates of $R$ is $(73,-100)$.

Then, by Pythagorean theorem, $PR^2=PI^2-IR^2$ and $QR^2=QI^2-IR^2$. Thus, $PR^2=19^2-7^2=312$. Therefore, x-coordinate of $P$ and $Q$ are $73-\sqrt{312}$ and $73+\sqrt{312}$, respectively (assume $P$ is closer to y-axis than $Q$).

Therefore, the coordinates of intersections of circle on leg $a$ are $\left((73-\sqrt{312}),-100\right)$ and $\left((73+\sqrt{312}),-100\right)$, respectively. Or approximately, $(55.34,-100)$ and $(90.66,-100)$.

Similarly, suppose two intersection of circle on the hypotenuse of the right-triangle are $S$ and $T$, thus $IS=IT=19$  (the radius of the circle). Since both $S$ and $T$ are on $y=-x$ line, magnitude of the coordinates of each point must be equal but have opposite sign. Let them be $S(m,-m)$ and $T(n,-n)$.  Now, suppose the parallel line goes through $I$ meets the perpendicular line goes through $S$ at $U$. Hence,the coordinates of $U$ must be $(m,-93)$. By Pythagorean theorem, $SU^2=SI^2-IU^2$. Therefore, $(m-93)^2=19^2-(73-m)^2$. Thus, $2m^2-(186+146)m+(93^2+73^2-19^2)=0$ or $2m^2-332m+13617=0$. Quadratic equation gives the solutions: $m=74.03$ or $m=91.97$.

Similarly, for point $T(n,-n)$, the Pythagorean theorem would be $TW^2=TI^2-IW^2$ where $W$ is the intersecting point of the line parallel to leg $a$, which goes through $I$ and the perpendicular line goes through $T$. Therefore, $(n-93)^2=19^2-(n-73)^2$, the solution for which would be the same as $n=74.03$ or $n=91.97$.

Thus, the coordinates of intersections of circle on the hypotenuse of the right-triangle are approximately, $(74.03,-74.03)$ (closest to x-axis) and $(91.97,-91.97)$ (farthest to x-axis).